# Equivalent of history expansion in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

In bash (or zsh), I type `!$` to get the last command's last argument, `!!` to get the entire line, etc. What is the equivalent (with the same ease of use) in Powershell? I see PSReadline has <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>, but looking for something that expands after I hit enter.

Comment: for get last command you run that in powershell you should use `$$` for run that with out see command `Invoke-Expression "$$"`

Comment: @SoheilHashemi that returns the last token of the last command. You might have already been aware of that but just know that it does not return the full command.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at [about_Automatic_Variables](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx) it contains details for how to get the first or last argument.

> - **$$**: Contains the last token in the last line received by the session.
> - **$^**: Contains the first token in the last line received by the session.

That should cover the use of `!$` in bash. Here is an example of their use:

```
PS Z:\> Get-ChildItem c:\temp -Directory
                                                                                         
... Output truncated...

PS Z:\> $$
-Directory

PS Z:\> $^
Get-ChildItem
```

Those would just returns the strings of what they represent. However it is not very useful for commands with more than 3 tokens.

As for `!!` one of the options you have is:

## Invoke-History

More on its use from [TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176881.aspx) but in its simplest form

```
PS Z:\> Get-Item c:\temp
   Directory: C:\
Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                                                                                                            
----                -------------     ------ ----                                                                                                            
d----          4/1/2015   3:06 PM            temp                                                                                                            

PS Z:\> r
Get-Item c:\temp

    Directory: C:\
Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                                                                                                            
----                -------------     ------ ----                                                                                                            
d----          4/1/2015   3:06 PM            temp
```

`r` is an alias for the `Invoke-History` cmdlet which you can use if you value brevity. You see that right below the `r` is the command that is being executed. That of course matches the line above.

## Get-History

As far as just returning a string, as supposed to actually executing it, then `Get-History` would be an offered solution. Although in practice it is not as terse as what is shown above.

```
(Get-History -Count 1).CommandLine
```

or for brevity using an alias and unambiguous parameter notation.

```
(h -c 1).CommandLine
```

That would return the last command that was entered. Since the History is an object collection we need to use the property to get what we are looking for. There is nothing stopping you from making this into a function and adding it to your profile though.

## PowerShell History Tab Completion

So this is new to me and I cannot find a Microsoft reference discussing it. Closest we have is a [blog post from Shay Levy at PowerShellMagazine](http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2013/07/11/pstip-using-tab-completion-against-the-command-history/).

It discusses using the number sign/sharp symbol to recall history commands to the console. To get the last command you would type `#` and then hit <kbd>tab</kbd>.

It also responds to history indexes. So to get the 3rd command from the start of your PowerShell session you would type `#3` and then hit <kbd>tab</kbd>

Comment: in linux `!!` or `!$` run last command and not show command for run last command is not right  use `Invoke-Expression "$^ $$" ` ?

Comment: @SoheilHashemi What happens when you try that when you run `Get-ChildItem c:\temp -Directory` first? It will be: `Get-ChildItem -Directory`. First and last token.

Comment: I would use `(Get-History -Count 1).CommandLine` instead of `((Get-History).CommandLine)[-1]`.

Comment: @PetSerAl that would be more ideal and less process heavy I suppose.

Comment: @Matt Don't forget #. To get the last command, type '#<TabKey>'. To get command number 1, type '#1<TabKey>'. You can also search through history by typing '#searchterm<TabKey>.

Comment: @RohnEdwards that's a thing? Will have to look that up

Comment: @Matt yep, and it's amazing! I'm not sure where it's documented, though.

Comment: @RohnEdwards Having issues finding a reference for it.

Comment: http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2013/07/11/pstip-using-tab-completion-against-the-command-history/

Comment: @Matt: I'm looking for something that is usable. Typing (Get-History -Count 1).CommandLine is long. Also, hitting enter just returns the string result and not invoke it. So I need  Invoke-Expression (Get-History -Count 1).CommandLine, which is even longer....

Comment: Did you see the section about invoke-history? Which does just that in my answer?

Comment: Any idea how to increase the number of completion items shown (10) to something else?